# Alternatives for InfoPath forms?

Tags: infopath

I've made some InfoPath forms, but have run into a number of problems when trying to put them on SharePoint, getting an error saying they are not "editable in browsers" despite being "browser enabled." If I can't fix this problem, I'm looking for alternatives (recognizing it would take more work to transfer all the stuff to the alternative). Essentially I just want something that can be filled out for free, but has good functionality in building the form. I'm willing to pay, just don't want my users to pay. Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

OOB SharePoint lists - Just a reminder that lists work OOB, and do have some nice customization options.

Microsoft Forms - I like this tool, very easy to use, but no customization opportunities. If they work, then you're up and running in minutes. (edit: but if you're moving from infopath, most likely this solution will be too simplistic and won't meet your needs)

PowerApps - The Microsoft recommended solution. On one hand, this is a very powerful tool and you can do a lot with it. On the other hand, it has a steep learning curve, is non-intuitive, slow, is no stranger to bugs, and since it has a different design purpose than infopath, it can be quite difficult to recreate infopath forms in powerapps.

3rd party - There are a variety of 3rd party tools available, such as Nintex Forms, though I personally haven't used them.

edit: another option is SPFx. This is a developer platform, but it does allow you to create custom forms, or any other web part as desired. Incredible possibilities, but most definitely not for just power users.

Comment: Microsoft Forms is intended for surveys instead of SharePoint custom forms. You should use Flow to save information to SharePoint, there isn't a mechanism to automatically save it into SP.

Comment: Another option is to just build your own.  Depending on your ability, and how much permissions you have, I have always done my own custom interfaces.  If you have the ability to deploy solutions, that is the best in my opinion.  PowerApps is actually really nice though and I like it much better than InfoPath if you can't code on your farm. InfoPath sucks! lol

Comment: Good point, I'll add an edit.

Answer (score 0):

InfoPath forms work well with Internet Explorer. Make sure that you're using IE 11+ to get best of InfoPath forms in SharePoint.

To answer your second part of the question, a few alternatives to InfoPath-

- Nintex Forms (paid)
- K2 Smartforms (paid)
- SharePoint Designer (free)
- PowerApps (comes with o365 package)

Answer (score 0):

I have worked personaly with **K2 Smart Form**. It is really powerfull Form option but it is not free and ,I think, it comes with their workflow engine. They have really powerfull and you can even implement workflow using its rule managements. It's fully support sharepoint tasks and comes in provider-hosted App model (at least the version I worked with it (4.7)) which needed a server for implementation although we install it in sharepoint server. These form editor have lots of functionality including Tab and Master-details support and even you can edit Forms that used in its workflow engine.

Also another Form Editor which I see in some companies is **BPC PowerForm** which as they say have lots of functionality including Master-Detail forms (repeated table connected to sharepoint lists and other data sources like sql servers) but I think it is not free too altough it has, I think, One month free trial. Customers are really happy with that but I personally doesnt work very much with it and so dont judge it. Both of them are available for On-Premise Environments.
The points about some Forms is that their design/runtime may need silverlight which may be a disadvantage due to support on Mozilla for example!